# Why regex always returns 1?

Tags: c, regex

The following function checks if a variable name start with a letter and may have preceding characters which are letters/ numbers. Why does the return value is always 1 no matter what the input is?

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int validate_var(char *str)
{
    regex_t reg;
    regcomp(&reg, "^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", 0);
    int r = regexec(&reg, str, 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&reg);

    return r;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", validate_var("abc")); // Reports 1, This makes sense
    printf("%d\n", validate_var("17"));  // Reports 1, This doesn't make sense
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a string which represents a variable name.

Comment: I mean what's the content.

Comment: Is it for example, `nul` terminated? how did you build/create `str`'s content?

Comment: @abcxyz: In general, it's helpful to give a full test case that can be used against the code. I've included that in the question.

Comment: @BillLynch I don't think it's a good edit, maybe OP is getting different values for this input.

Comment: *"Normally, regexec() returns 0 for success and the non-zero code REG_NOMATCH for failure.  Other non-zero error codes may be returned in exceptional situations;"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using anchors (`^` and `$`) but not enabling extended syntax by passing `REG_EXTENDED` to `regcomp()`. [See the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp).

You should really check all return values, there should be a failure reported somewhere due to the syntax usage error.

Note that non-zero means failure.

Comment: And apparently the OP thinks that `1` means success.

Comment: To complete unwind's answer, `regcomp()` should always return `0` if successful. Check this [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html).

Comment: Can you give a couple of words about `REG_EXTENDED`? When shall be used?

Comment: @iharob, I actually know that `0` is success, otherwise failure or not-found.

Comment: @iharob: Yeah. That was my mistake in trying to improve the question.

Comment: regcomp returns 0 in this example. https://ideone.com/xbLLgz. Its regexec returning the error.